# Rails query objects by key value of hash saved to column?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, hash

I have 2 objects, Visitors and Events. Visitors have multiple Events. An event stores parameters like this...

```
#<Event id: 5466, event_type: "Visit", visitor_token: "c26a6098-64bb-4652-9aa0-e41c214f42cb", contact_id: 657, data: {"url"=>"http://widget.powerpress.co/", "title"=>"Home (light) | Widget"}, created_at: "2015-12-17 14:51:53", updated_at: "2015-12-17 14:51:53", website_id: 2>
```

As you can see, there is a serialized text column called data that stores a hash with more data.

I need to find out if a visitor has visited a certain page, which would be very simple if the url parameter were it's own column, or if the hash were an hstore column, however it wasn't originally set up that way and it's a part of the saved hash.

Here's my attempted rails queries...

```
visitor.events.where("data -> url = :value", value: 'http://widget.powerpress.co/')

visitor.events.where("data like ?", "{'url' => 'http://widget.powerpress.co/'}")

visitor.events.where("data -> :key LIKE :value", :key => 'url', :value => "%http://widget.powerpress.co/%")
```

How does one properly query postgres to find objects that have a hash that contains a key with a specific value?

Comment: the `data` column is a String ?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're not looking for the right string. It should be `"url"=>"http://widget.powerpress.co/"`, so:

```
visitor.events.where("data like ?", '%"url"=>"http://widget.powerpress.co/"%')
```

Check the right value directly in DB.

Comment: While this runs it doesn't return anything (there are for sure events with that url btw). I can successfully run `Event.where("data like ?", '%http://widget.powerpress.co/%')` however this includes events with urls like /blog etc. Any work around?

Comment: Can you add to your post an actual value of the column `data` from the DB ? You posted an exemple from Rails, but the format may be different in DB.

Comment: Event.last.attributes_before_type_cast returns `{"id"=>"5466", "event_type"=>"View", "visitor_token"=>"c26a6098-64bb-4652-9aa0-e41c214f42cb", "contact_id"=>"657", "data"=>{"url"=>"http://widget.powerpress.co/", "title"=>"Home (light) | Widget", "page"=>"/", "time"=>"1450363908.892", "contactable_name"=>"overlay theme 8"}, "created_at"=>"2015-12-17 14:51:53.9496", "updated_at"=>"2015-12-17 14:51:53.9496", "website_id"=>"2", "tag_id"=>nil, "contactable_type"=>"Overlay", "contactable_id"=>"87", "visitor_id"=>"117", "broadcast_id"=>nil, "flow_id"=>"7", "stage_id"=>nil, "goal_id"=>"5", "url"=>nil}`

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing hash in a text column, try following:

```
visitor.events.select{|ve| eval(ve.data)["url"] == "http://widget.powerpress.co/"}
```

Hope, it helps!

Comment: `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into String`

Comment: Interesting. Please post the output of `Event` from rails console.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me.

```
 visitor.events.select { |n| n.data && n.data['url'] == "http://widget.powerpress.co/"}
```